# Log in input with lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I have no clue how to use lambda functions. I made this simple code, but now I am trying to rewrite my code using lambda functions while keeping the general instructions.

```
username_password = {"Maria":"hola","Victoria":"bye"} 

def main():
   for x in range(5): 
       login_username = input("Please enter your username.\n") 
       login_password = input("Please enter your password.\n")  

       if login_username in username_password and login_password == username_password[login_username]: 
           print("Logged in")
           break
       else:
           print("\ntry again please")
   else: 
      print("incorrect username / password, kicked off of the system")
      


main()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like the kind of situation where you'd want to use lambdas. Why do you feel the need to use them here?

Comment: Lambda functions are like the function version of list comprehensions. You should only use them for defining short/readable functions.

Comment: you can write the entire function in one line with lambdas, is it worth? as a joke, yes; as an exercise, not really.  I personally can't find any place in your code where a lambda function might improve readability.

Comment: I want to use the lambda function because it is what my professor asks me for.

Comment: @AlanCalderon did they asked to use lambda in this code? if not it might be better for you to come up with a different example (eg. searching accounts in a list that obey certain conditions)

Comment: They asked me to rewrite this code but using lambda functions, but honestly, I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is not correct. Second it is not recommend to use lamda to achieve these kind of problem. Please read this:
https://dbader.org/blog/python-lambda-functions

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty vague, but I'll try to give you some ideas.

These changes don't make the code any nicer to read, but just to give you an example on where you can use lambdas... which is anywhere a single statement is used.

Combining lambda with simple transform methods like `map` allows you to do some pretty interesting (although overly complicated) things:

```
username_password = {"Maria": "hola", "Victoria": "bye"}
user_input = lambda: input("Please enter your username.\n")
pass_input = lambda: input("Please enter your password.\n")
check_login = lambda u, pw: username_password.get(u) == pw
ask_input = lambda *_: check_login(user_input(), pass_input())


def main():
    for logged_in in map(ask_input, range(5)):
        if logged_in:
            print("Logged in")
            break
        else:
            print("try again please")
    else:
        print("incorrect username / password, kicked off of the system")


main()
```